# How to set align - center image and texts in row Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to align the image to center each text. Below is my code. I tried it using container,. but it doesn't work.

and below is the picture.

[image]

```
  <section id="features">
    <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text">
        <img src="images/feature1.png" alt="feature1">
        <h3 class="features-title">Food Listing.</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Quickly and easily post information about food you want to share.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text">
        <img src="images/feature2.png" alt="feature2">
        <h3 class="features-title">Matchmaking</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Find people in your area looking for food.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text">
        <img src="images/feature3.png" alt="feature3">
        <h3 class="features-title">Request System.</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Request food from other users with a few taps.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- </div> -->
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**,

Add `text-center` each one like this,

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text text-center">
```

Code:

```
  <section id="features">
    <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->

    <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text text-center">
        <img src="images/feature1.png" alt="feature1">
        <h3 class="features-title">Food Listing.</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Quickly and easily post information about food you want to share.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text text-center">
        <img src="images/feature2.png" alt="feature2">
        <h3 class="features-title">Matchmaking</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Find people in your area looking for food.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 title-text text-center">
        <img src="images/feature3.png" alt="feature3">
        <h3 class="features-title">Request System.</h3>
        <p class="features-prgrph">Request food from other users with a few taps.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- </div> -->
  </section>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the class text-center in the div with the class title-text.